# access JavaScript file in a java method in tomcat

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat

I want to access a JavaScript file using a Java Method in tomcat. I put js file in Web-INF folder and used engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("fileName.js")); in a java method to access it. but it doesn't detect the js file and always throws the java.io.FileNotFoundException .please help me to solve this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), you can read the file like this:

```
ServletContext context;
InputStream jsStream = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/fileName.js");
```

If you don't have access to the `ServletContext`, your best bet is to move the javascript file to the `classes` folder inside `WEB-INF`, and read it through the [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
InputStream jsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName.js");
```